# "zu"-Satz und "dass"-Satz

Tags: sentence-structure, infinitive

In verschiedenen Lernmaterialien heißt es, dass man einen dass-Satz in eine zu-Konstruktion verwandeln kann, so die Subjekte in Haupt- und Nebensatz übereinstimmen. Es gibt dann manchmal noch eine Liste von Ausnahmen, bei denen nur der dass-Satz funktioniert.

In der Praxis führt das jedoch zu unidiomatischen Verwendungen, die mehr oder weniger falsch klingen.

> Ich weiß, kommen zu können.... so gut wie gar nicht gut.
>
> Ich weiß, dass ich kommen kann.... klar besser.

.

> Ich versuche, dass ich nicht zu spät komme.... nicht so gut (wenn auch mittlerweile nicht unselten)
>
> Ich versuche, nicht zu spät zu kommen... klar besser.

Meine Frage ist die:

- Gibt es tieferliegende Gemeinsamkeiten aller Verben, die mit einer zu-Konstruktion besser funktionieren?

oder anders gefragt:

- Gibt es einen Weg, am Verb des Hauptsatzes (an der Aktion) zu erkennen, ob ein dass-Satz oder ein zu-Satz zu bevorzugen ist, OHNE die Sprache zu kennen?

Comment: Sollen die Beispielsätze zusammen passen? Der erste Satz klingt in der Tat nicht so gut, wie der zweite, aber der ist keine Umforumung des zweiten Satzes. "Ich denke, dass ich kommen kann" bzw. "Ich versuche nicht zu spät zu kommen" sind die Gegensätze. Und letzerer klingt in beiden Varianten (fast) gleich gut (anders hingegen wenn das Verb *sein* ist). Und in beiden Fällen ist es "kommen", also am Verb kannst du es schon mal nicht erkennen.

Comment: @Em: nee... dass sollen beides Beispiele sein, die nicht so gut funktionieren. Das zweite ist akzeptable, aber ich würde die zu-Variante klar vorziehen. Das Verb ist allerdings nicht kommen. Im Nebensatz ist es einmal "können" und einmal "kommen". Mir geht es aber um das Verb im Hauptsatz. Ich will wissen ob sich daraus das die Wahl des Ergänzungssatzes anhand von Kriterien ableiten lässt.

Comment: Oups, you're right. *Kommen* ist einmal im Infinitiv. My bad. - Also du beziehst dich auf "denken" bzw. "versuchen"?

Comment: Um dem zweiten Beispiel Nachdruck zu geben, verwende einfach wirklich *sein*: "Ich versuche, nicht zu spät zu sein." vs "Ich versuche, dass ich nicht zu spät bin"

Comment: Und ich hab das jetzt so 20x im Kopf wiederholt und es klingt von mal zu mal scheusslicher. Aber was ist mit "Ich versuche, dass ich nicht zu spät kommen werde" oder "Ich versuche, dass ich nicht zu spät sein werde", ich glaube im Fall von "ich denke" würde ich auf jeden Fall daruaf ausweichen. vgl: "Ich denke, dass ich pünktlich sein werde" - "Ich denke, dass ich pünktlich bin" - "Ich denke püntklich zu sein". Ha, wobei ich glaube zu wissen, was der Unterschied zwischen *denken* und *versuchen* ist. Ich muss aber in Ruhe drüber nachdenken. to be continued as soon as I'm sure.

Comment: „wenn auch mittlerweile nicht unselten“: Naa, ich hob kaane doppelte Vernaanung ned g’hört.

Comment: Ich fürchte kritisieren zu müssen, dass "Ich denke, kommen zu können." völlig sauber klingt.

Comment: @userunknown: ich find's zwar nicht gut aber ich sehe, dass man da diskutieren kann... ich habe es zu "Ich weiß" geändert. Das funktioniert doch nun wirklich nicht mit zu,oder?

Comment: Ne, höchstens im übertragenen Sinne. :) Moment - mit trotzigem Unterton vielleicht? "Du hast doch am Mittwoch kegeln und Chor - wie willst Du es da schaffen meiner Mutter zu gratulieren?" "Ich weiß, kommen zu können!" Mein erster Impuls war aber, Dir Recht zu geben.

Answer (score 3):

Wenn es nicht gut klingt, liegt das nicht an den Verben, sondern am Satzbau. Die erste Variante im ersten Beispiel klingt schlecht, weil drei Verben in Folge genannt werden, was das Erfassen des Inhaltlichen erschwert. Mit der zweiten Variante wird das durch die trennende Konjunktion gut aufgelöst. Nicht nur die Aufeinanderfolge von Verben, sondern auch dieses im Gemisch mit Adverbien und Adjektiven macht das Verstehen schwer, da die Wörter gedanklich funktional erst zugeordnet werden müssen. Das logische Trennen durch Konjunktionen bzw. Neuzuordnung über Personalpronomen macht den Satz verdaulicher und lockert auf.

Im zweiten Beispiel klingt Variante 1 (mit dem *dass*) klar besser und wird von den meisten Menschen, die ich kenne, auch umgangssprachlich bevorzugt. Variante 2 klingt schriftsprachlich, ist aber auch nicht schlecht, da auch hier die Konzentration von Verben durch den gewählten Satzbau vermieden wird. Ungünstig wirkt sich hier nur die Dopplung von *zu* aus, die den Satz etwas kompliziert wirken lässt.

Comment: Schön, dass du's versuchst aber ich kann leider absolut nicht zustimmen. Hier mein Gegenbeispiel gegen den ersten Teil deiner These: "Thomas denkt, dass er schlau ist." vs. "Thomas denkt schlau zu sein"... keine 2 Verben und trotzdem funktioniert die "zu"-Version nicht. Was Teil 2 deiner These angeht... ich bin mir ziemlich sicher, dass die "zu"-Version Hochdeutsch ist und die Version mit dass schlechter Stil, sei es gesprochen oder geschrieben. Aber sei's drum. Hier ein anderes Beispiel: "Ich versuche, dass ich die Tür aufmache." vs "Ich versuche, die Tür aufzumachen.". Also -1

Comment: "Ich denke, dass ich Recht habe." vs. "Ich denke, Recht zu haben."... kein Adjektiv

Comment: recht haben -> siehe adjektivische Bedeutung von recht (http://www.korrekturen.de/kurz_erklaert/recht_haben_oder_recht_haben.shtml), also wieder Verb/Adjektiv-Gemisch

Comment: "Ich versuche, dass ich die Tür aufmache." vs "Ich versuche, die Tür aufzumachen." -> klingt für mich beides gleich gut. Lässt sich auch gut mit der Antwort oben erklären.

Comment: @falkb "Ich versuche, dass ich die Tür aufmache" ist unterirdisch. Definitiv die zweite Variante.

Comment: @Em1: LOL, hier hilft wohl nur noch der Publikumsjoker ;)

Comment: @Em1: Ich behaupte der Publikumjoker zu sein. "Ich versuche dass ich die Tür aufmache" ist auch in meinen Augen unterirdisch. "Ich versuche die Tür zu öffnen." :)