# "zu"-Konstruktion für "dass ich alle Fragen beantworten konnte"

Tags: grammar, infinitive

> Es freut mich, dass ich alle Fragen beantworten konnte.

Wie stellt man diesen Satz in einer "zu"-Konstruktion? Ich kann mir nur dieses ausdenken:

> Es freut mich, alle Fragen beantworten können zu haben.

Gibt es keine Präteritumversion?

Comment: Related: [“zu”-Satz und “dass”-Satz](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8011/zu-satz-und-dass-satz)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Da sich das *haben* auf *können* bezieht und das Perfekt ausdrückt, muss das Partizip für *können* verwendet werden:

> Es freut mich, alle Fragen beantworten **gekonnt** zu haben

Der Satz klingt allerdings sehr ungewöhnlich und würde so in der Regel nicht ausgesprochen werden. Man sollte solchen komplizierten Formulierungen immer einen *dass*-Satz vorziehen.

Zu deiner zweiten Frage: Das Präteritum ist mit einem *zu*-Satz nicht möglich. Es kann hier entweder das Präsens oder das Perfekt, welches dann für beliebige Vorzeitigkeit stehen kann, verwendet werden.

Comment: Eine alte Quelle: https://books.google.de/books?id=nIxCAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA447&lpg=PA447&dq=%22+k%C3%B6nnen+zu+haben%22&source=bl&ots=xHGK9lyV3N&sig=1c4NKmXuRvQFNVHYlntcBCSSs_0&hl=de&sa=X&ei=zFCXVL3yOofyPJrqgPgP&ved=0CEIQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=%22%20k%C3%B6nnen%20zu%20haben%22&f=false und 2 neue: https://books.google.de/books?id=XjateRnTp84C&pg=PA92&dq=%22gekonnt+zu+haben%22&hl=de&sa=X&ei=GFGXVIfxA4OsPbqjgJgH&ved=0CCIQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22gekonnt%20zu%20haben%22&f=false

Comment: https://books.google.de/books?id=iw2SAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA191&dq=%22gekonnt+zu+haben%22&hl=de&sa=X&ei=GFGXVIfxA4OsPbqjgJgH&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22gekonnt%20zu%20haben%22&f=false  ... die sagen alle "gekonnt zu haben"

Answer (score 4):

Bei *können* und einigen anderen Verben, die sich mit einem Infinitiv verbinden können, wird im *haben*-Perfekt das Partizip II durch den sogenannten Ersatzinfinitiv ersetzt, wenn ihm ein Infinitiv vorangeht.

> Ich *habe* es nicht *verhindern können.*
> <s>Ich habe es nicht verhindern gekonnt.</s>

Allerdings tritt im Infinitiv des Perfekts das Partizip II auf, wenn (laut Duden – *Richtiges und gutes Deutsch*) der *zu*-Infinitiv von *haben* verwendet wird bzw. wenn (etwas allgemeiner laut Duden – *Grammatik*) *haben* am Ende steht. (Sonst nimmt der Ersatzinfinitiv die Endstellung ein.)

> Sie wird ihn *haben laufen sehen.*
> Ich erinnere mich, ihn *laufen **gesehen** zu haben.*
>
> Er wird ihn *haben kommen lassen.*
> Ich erinnere mich, sie früher das Bild *sehen **gelassen** zu haben.*
>
> Sie wird nicht *haben kommen können.*
> Er wird nicht *kommen **gekonnt** haben.*

Dementsprechend muss es heißen:

> Es freut mich, alle Fragen *beantworten **gekonnt** zu haben.*
> <s>Es freut mich, alle Fragen beantworten können zu haben.</s>