# "zu"-Konstruktion von "dass ich sie gehen sehen musste"

Tags: grammar, infinitive

> Es reut mich, dass ich sie gehen sehen musste.

Wie stellt man diesen Satz in eine "zu"-Konstruktion? Wäre es das Folgende?

> Es reut mich, sie gehen sehen **gemusst** zu haben.

(*Bemerkung*: Verwandt ist [diese Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/18692/zu-konstruktion-f%C3%BCr-dass-ich-alle-fragen-beantworten-konnte), jedoch ohne die zusätzliche Komplizierung von "gehen sehen musste". Ich glaube, dass dasselbe Prinzip noch gilt, aber diese Konstruktion von zwei Verben plus einem Modalverb haben die Antworten zu der erwähnten Frage noch nicht behandelt.)

Comment: In der Praxis würde man die Vorzeitigkeit ignorieren (ergibt sich notfalls aus dem Kontext), und einfach "Es reut mich, sie gehen sehen zu müssen" sagen. Zu komplizierte Konstruktionen sind kein guter Stil.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ja, das Prinzip gilt noch. Es wird einfach immer das letzte finite Verb zu einem Partizip Perfekt umgeformt, ob es sich dabei um ein Hilfsverb handelt, ist unerheblich.

Das ganze lässt sich ins Unendliche fortsetzen:

> Es reut mich, sie gehen gelassen zu haben.
>   Es reut mich, sie gehen lassen gedurft zu haben.
>     Es reut mich, sie gehen lassen dürfen gewollt zu haben.

Spätestens bei 2 Infinitiven + Modalverb im Partizip wird man aber vermutlich von seinem Gesprächspartner schief angeschaut werden.