# Grammatik in "wird nicht kommen gekonnt haben"

Tags: grammar, word-order

Zwei Sätze aus Loongs Antwort zu [dieser Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/18692/zu-konstruktion-f%C3%BCr-dass-ich-alle-fragen-beantworten-konnte) (mit kleiner Modifizierung):

> (a) Er wird nicht haben kommen können.
>
> (b) Er wird nicht kommen gekonnt haben.

Wie ich verstehe, bedeuten die beiden Sätze genau dasselbe. Was ich nicht ganz verstehe ist, warum (b) grammatikalisch richtig sein kann. Es ist keine "zu"-Konstruktion, denn das Wörtchen "zu" tritt gar nicht auf. Warum kann man "haben" ans Ende des Satzes stellen?

Comment: Das ist eine gute Frage, warum nicht "kommen können haben". Ich weiß nicht warum oder seit wann, aber drei Infinitive hintereinander ist verpönt. In solchen Fällen hat Deutsch besondere Stellungsregeln (bei Modalverben), die manche Leute gar nicht kennen. Hier verheddern sich so manche Deutsche. Ich vermeide solche ungelenken Konstruktionen, wenn es geht. Ich würde sagen: Vielleicht war es ihm unmöglich zu kommen.

Comment: @rogermue... Zitat: "drei Infinitive hintereinander ist verpönt" So einfach ist es nicht. "Ich habe Klaviel spielen lernen wollen" ist total ok.

Comment: @boaten... ich sehe das Problem nicht. Warum sollte "haben" denn nicht am Ende sein?

Comment: @Emauel - Mag sein. Ich würde sagen: Ich wollte schon immer Klavier spielen lernen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Der Satz (b) ist korrekt, da er im [Futur II](http://www.mein-deutschbuch.de/lernen.php?menu_id=111) steht. Das Futur II kann entweder für Vermutungen, die Vergangenheit betreffend, oder für Vorhersagen über abgeschlossene Handlungen in der Zukunft verwendet werden. Es wird mit werden + Perfekt gebildet:

> Er kommt ➔ Er wird gekommen sein
>   Er kann kommen ➔ Er wird kommen gekonnt haben

Der Satz (a) ist durch den [Ersatzinfinitiv](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ersatzinfinitiv) korrekt.

Comment: Nach meinem Sprachgefühl ist das falsch. Futur II von "Er kann kommen" ist "Er wird haben kommen können".